# How to create variable page title for a set of custom taxonomy pages

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to set up a variable page title for posts in a custom taxonomy in WordPress

I need the title to be e.g. some text + default post page title

So in other words I just want to include the original post title but for it to also include my edit. I have a child theme and to my knowledge there isn't a custom template page for this taxonomy. Would I need to add the code into the archives.php page?

any help would be much appreciated
thanks!

Comment: Do you want to change the title in the archive page or the single page of the custom taxonomy?

Comment: Hey Sagar, many thanks for your reply. I would like to change the single page of the custom taxonomy

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'modify_the_title', 10, 2 );
function modify_the_title( $title, $id ) {
    // Check for archive page.
    if ( is_archive() && is_tax( 'your-custom-taxonomy') ) {
       $title = 'some text' . $title;
        return $title;
    }
}
```

Reference: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_title/

Comment: I just tried this but it's not working - I tried adding it to my functions.php and archive.php

Comment: @RobertLouis Add it in the functions.php file and enable the WP_DEBUG true in the wp-config.php file and view the page.

Comment: Hi Sagar, I appreciate you trying to help but it's still not working when I add it to the functions.php file.